# Widget crashes, after trying to get DB instance

Tags: android, android-widget, android-room, android-context

I am building a widget for a Baking App, which retrieves data from a ROOM db.
If i close the app the widget crashes and i get the following error

```
Process: com.example.android.bakingapp, PID: 5714
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.android.bakingapp.DB.AppDatabase.getInstance(AppDatabase.java:26)
    at com.example.android.bakingapp.DB.RecipeRepository.<init>(RecipeRepository.java:22)
    at com.example.android.bakingapp.widget.BakingAppRemoteViewsFactory.onDataSetChanged(RecipeService.java:58)
    at android.widget.RemoteViewsService$RemoteViewsFactoryAdapter.onDataSetChanged(RemoteViewsService.java:142)
    at com.android.internal.widget.IRemoteViewsFactory$Stub.onTransact(IRemoteViewsFactory.java:50)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

So i am calling `getApplicationContext()` on a null object - whereas the null object is my app, right?

How should i approach this? How am i going to get a DB instance w/o the object application which is returned by the `getApplicationContext()`

Below is where the error occurs

```
public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context){
    if (sInstance == null){
        synchronized (LOCK){
            sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the db instance");
    return sInstance;
}
public abstract RecipesDao recipesDao();
```

}

And

```
class BakingAppRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory{

private static String RECIPE_ID="recipe_id";
private static String RECIPE_NAME="recipe_name";
private final Context mContext;
private Recipe recipe;
private int recipeID;
private RecipeRepository recipeRepository;
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();

public BakingAppRemoteViewsFactory (Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
    recipeID = sharedPreferences.getInt(RECIPE_ID, 0);
    recipeRepository = new RecipeRepository(BakingApp.getContext());
    recipe = recipeRepository.getCurrentRecipe(recipeID);
    ingredients = recipe.getRecipeIngredients();
}
```

This is what im passing to the getInstance() call

```
public class BakingApp extends Application {
private static BakingApp mContext;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
}
public static BakingApp getContext(){return mContext;}
```

`public RecipeRepository(Application application){
        AppDatabase appDatabase =AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
        recipesDao = appDatabase.recipesDao();
    }`

Comment: `Context context` is null. You are passing `null` into `public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context)` call. Look for the error wherever you are calling `getInstance`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko please see my edit

Comment: you didn't show what you pass into `getInstance()`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko edited my post again